# Angular - Reactive Forms - Binding object inside of object

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, binding, angular-reactive-forms

I created FormGroup and initialized FormGroup with one formControlName (`SerialNumber`).
SerialNumber JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "SerialNumber": {
        "snValue": "332432"
    }
}
```

I don't know how to bind `SerialNumber.snValue` to the `<input>`. I always get `[object Object]` instead of `332432`.

**.ts code**

```
equipmentForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.equipmentForm = this.fb.group({
     serialNumber: {"snValue": "332432"}
     })
}
```

**.html**

```
<input type="text" formControlName="serialNumber" />
```

My question is, how to bind `snValue`?

[image]

Comment: If you're going to use `FormBuilder`, use it properly. See: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#using-the-formbuilder-service-to-generate-controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you already have your object `obj`, you can do this :

```js
obj = {
  "SerialNumber": {
    "snValue": "332432"
  }
};

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.equipmentForm = this.fb.group({
     serialNumber: [obj.SerialNumber.snValue]
   });
}
```